# Using a custom ID for mongoose schema

Tags: mongoose

I'm wondering if there is a good approach for assigning custom (user friendly) ID's to a schema. I want my own ID to be something like '1234' not the ObjectID automatically assigned by mongoose. The app I'm creating is a task management app so I want each task created to have an easy to read id which can be entered in a search box and then be brought to that particular task.

My schema

```
var tickitSchema = Schema({
title               : String,
description         : String,
completed           : Boolean,
priority            : Number,
category            : Number,
customId            : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'TickitNumber'}, 
updatedAt           : {type: Date},
author              : { 
    type            : Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref             : 'User' 
},
comments            : [{
    body            : String,
    by              : {
       type         : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref          : 'User'
    }
}],
boardToBeDisplayedOn: [{
    type            : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref             : 'Board'
}]
```

});

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;

var tickitNumberSchema = Schema({
    tickitId : Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('TickitNumber', tickitNumberSchema);
```

Then on my server side API (node/express) I have a function for creating a task.

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
  var tickit = Tickit(req.body);
  tickit.category = 1;
  for(i = 0; i < TickitNumber.length; i++) {
    var tn = TickitNumber[i] + 1;
  }
  if(!req.body.title) {
    res.status(400);
    res.send('Title is required');
  } else {
  var data = [];
  tickit.author = req.user;
  tickit.boardToBeDisplayedOn = req.user.ownsBoard;
  tickit.customId = tn;

  tickit.save(function (err, tickit) {
    if (err || tickit === null) { return res.send(err || new Error('Tickit was not saved but there was no error...odd')); }
    async.parallel([
      function(callback) {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, {$push: {userTickits: tickit}}, {new: true}, function (err, user) {
          if (err) return callback(err);
          data.push(tickit);
          callback();// or whatever else you want to send
        })
      },

      function(callback) {
        Board.findByIdAndUpdate(tickit.boardToBeDisplayedOn,{$push: {boardTickits: tickit}}, {new:true}, function(err, board){
          if(err) return res.send(err) ;
          data.push(board);
          callback();
        })
      }
    ], function(err) {
        if(err) return next(err);

        res.status(201);
        res.json(tickit);
      });
  });
}  
}
```

If anyone knows of a better way of doing this or improving what I've already done it would be really helpful, thanks!

Comment: If you're only ever going to be running this on a single instance(server), you likely won't run into any problems with this. However, the moment you start having multiple instances updating the same database, or a database cluster, you will run into race conditions with this kind of id generation. [Read more here](https://blog.serverdensity.com/switching-to-mongodb-and-auto-increment/).

Comment: You're better off having the `_id` be an ObjectId and then having a second field that has your user friendly ID, and have an index on it.

Comment: It will just be a single instance. I should have mentioned that I will still be using _id as an ObjectID, but I do want to have a secondary one that users can use. E.g a user can create a task and associate it with an existing task by supplying that ID. Am I on the right track with the above code? I've tested the method with POSTMAN but am getting a cast error.